# Touch Bar - Alternate Key Combination to Show App controls

Tags: touch-bar

Hope someone can help.

I have my touch configured like the following. This is basically the same setting that you got with the Mac Book Pros 2012 - 2015 as default.

[image]

I am a developer and use code editors so it's very important to me that my function keys are the first class citizens on my keyboard. I also want access to the control strip for screen and volume control using the fn keys (How else can I easily get to these?).

Great!

So now how do I access the "App Controls" as well? Surly I should be able to configure say fn+option to give me these?

Finding this very frustrating, makes the touch bar seem even more pointless if I can only have the settings I was used to with a "Real" keyboard. Seems I have to give something up to use the touch bar's app specific controls.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/).

---

I don't see a way to have the Touch Bar display function keys (initially) AND allow for the use of both App Controls and Control Strip.

Aren't you accustomed to holding <kbd>fn</kbd> when using the function keys anyway? I think this is the behavior Apple had in mind (show App Controls and use <kbd>fn</kbd> for function keys).

Instead of an additional keyboard shortcut, I'd suggest Apple add a "Show Control Strip" box on the the Fn setting when you choose App Controls (like the first drop down behaves).

---

Worst case: use an external keyboard when developing.

Comment: Not really as when debugging I will use the function keys to step through, in and out of code, at the same time it's good to use the trackpad / cursor to inspect variables as i'm stepping over them. I don't have 3 hands so using the fn key as well is too difficult. I see lots of developers complaining about the touch bar, seems we were forgotten by apple :/

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but here's what I've done as a compromise:

In System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Function Keys, I add all applications where I want to have Fn keys as default. These are basically code editors, terminals, browsers etc. That way, when I'm developing, I will always see the function keys.

In almost all other apps (messaging, video calls, calendar etc.) I find the App controls + Control Strip default more useful, so I leave that as the default for all other apps. I've noticed that I rarely if ever use the Fn keys in these apps.

To me this is the only half-decent solution without buying Better Touch Tools.